# Java - JFileChooser & file size

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am trying to get the size of a file from JFileChooser so that I can print it in table, how do I do that?

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

String[] fileNames = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().list();
int fileSize;

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    int fileSize = fileNames[i] //How do I get the size of the file here?
    model.addRow(new Object[]{fileNames[i], fileSize});

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
File[] files = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().listFiles();
```

and then use the for loop with the method length() from the File class to get the file size, i.e.,

```
int fileSize = files[i].length();
```

Answer (score 3):

Get a list of files (instead of file names) and then just call "length()" on them:

```
File[] files = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    int fileSize = files[i].length();
    model.addRow(new Object[]{fileNames[i], fileSize});

}
```